# Is flair tab working correctly?

Tags: bug, flair

Is the flair tab working correctly?

It is counting aproximately 3 times more points and over 2 times more bronze badges at the time I'm posting it.

Comment: Can you indicate what the numbers are you see? Because for me your [flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/67408.png) shows 10k with 267/39/6 and if I query SEDE I get roughly the same [results](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/629768) certainly not what you claim.

Comment: it should be 3,3k and 130 bronze badges

Comment: which was what displayed a few days ago by the way

Comment: add them up manually and you'll get that figure

Comment: The data from SEDE doesn't lie. That is the combined rep and badge count you have. If I add up rep found on the [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/67408/pablo?tab=accounts) I get 9097 (used this: `sum=0; $('.account-number').each(function() { var v=this; var sib=$(this).next(); if(sib[0].textContent === 'reputation') { sum+= parseInt(v.textContent,10); } }); console.log(sum);`). Please [edit] your question to explain to me how and where you do your calculations to reach your conclusion.

Comment: was it lying a few days before? it's pretty simple, supposedly you are counting only over 200 rep account, add up 1227 + 743 + 565 + 309 + 218 + 205 it gives less than 3300 , which is what was displaying a few days ago as I already said, and I have the bad habit of checking it almost daily, you can check my profile to see those are the only accounts I have over 200 rep, you either changed the calculation method in the last days and you count accounts with less than 200 rep or something (which anyway it doesnt give that) or there is a bug

Comment: Ok, I see, so if I leave out the sites where you have < 200 rep I get close to what you want it be. I always assumed the 200 rep boundary was only for the sites that appear on the flair, not for the sum of rep and badges. Anyway, needs a dev or PM to clarify.

Comment: In the [stack exchange flair tab](http://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=flair), they clearly mention that **please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.**. So it should be a _bug_ only