# Should my flair be including sites with less than 200 reputation?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, combined-flair

I took a look at my profile, where I stuck my flair. Here's the flair:

[image: 28k rep, with icons for scifi, puzzling, literature, Meta, area 51,elu,and AI]

However, I don't have 28k rep. According to chat, I have 19.7k.

Note: I *know* about the combined flair - I've had this in my profile for at least a year. It had been showing me the same as in chat, now it isn't.

What is going on here?

Edit: I'm reporting a bug here, that the combined flair is not showing the correct number, as it has in the past.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your accounts under 200 rep are erroneously being counted. You have 91 communities, of which 12 are over 200 and **should** be counted. If we assume you have 101 rep on all your other communites, `101 * 79 = 7979`, and `19700 + 7979 = 27679`, which rounds to 28k. I tried the same on my profile and my guess worked there too, so that's what I think is happening.

Comment: The combined flair calculated the <200 rep communities too. [Related or Dup post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291205). As per the [Stack Exchange Flair tab](http://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=flair), it should calculate the >200 rep communities only. There is some filter missed in the combined flair rep calculation

Comment: @Aurora0001 that was my guess too, but I hadn't done the math yet.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77716/260388

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, because the question this is closed as a duplicate of is virtually uninvestigatable and people are voting to close it as unclear. *This* one is something we can practically respond to and look into.

Comment: Heh, I have more rep from the association bonus than I do from actual contributions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A tiny bit of backstory: stackexchange.com used to be a separate solution (in the .NET sense), so it talked to Q&A through a set of API calls, both public and private. It's been a part of the normal Stack Overflow solution for going on two years now, and we've been slowly removing these API calls, replacing them with direct access to models and whatnot.

A lot of refactoring happened recently around how we track badge counts. Alongside that, we also took the opportunity to remove one more of those legacy accesses - this time, to the list of sites a user has profiles on. You may see where I'm going with this... the reputation check was accidentally omitted at that point.

The check is back in now, so flairs should be generating correctly if not now (because caching) then Soon<sup>TM</sup>.

Comment: What about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289982/badges-loading-broken-in-election-statistics)? Also due to the refactoring?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, the badge refactoring happened weeks after that report. That's something different.

Comment: Thanks. While not fatal, is the a fix planned for that?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Uh, maybe? Nobody's actively working on anything API-related AFAIK, but that doesn't mean a fix can't be made. It's also not entirely clear to me what's still broken after Tim's answer.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize the linked StackApps bug was fixed. I asked Tim is there's still any problem with the API, guess that if not the question I linked to can be marked [tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 12):

> What is going on here?

What is going on here is that the full total is being displayed in the flair.

I added up the [numbers](http://pastebin.com/tEWZ5nR2) on your [network profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/5129611/mithrandir?tab=accounts) and the total is indeed 28347. Rounded down, that's 28k.

So, the number there is the correct true total. Whether or not it *should* be counting 101 point sites is a different story, of course.

Note that adding up only numbers > 200 yields 19813, which is what chat displays (lagged behind by a day or so).

The description [on the flair tab page](https://stackexchange.com/users/305991/jason-c?tab=flair)...

> (please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.)

...is somewhat vaguely worded and open to interpretation. It could be interpreted as only sites > 200 will be included in both the total and logo list, or it could be interpreted as only sites > 200 will appear in the logo list (with no constraints on the total).

Comment: That has already been ascertained. The problem is, is that sites with < 200 rep should *not* be counted.

Comment: @ChrisF The problem in this post is vaguely defined. I cannot determine if the OP's primary concern is that flair does not match chat, that chat does not match the unfiltered mathematical total, or if the OP trusted chat to represent the total and did not realize they had 28k total, regardless of the flair/chat mismatch. Note when I say "total" I mean the true total (all numbers included). I can only address the directly asked question "What is going on here?" What is going on is the full total is being displayed in the flair, the filtered total is being displayed in the chat.

Comment: @ChrisF they are counted (e.g. user with account on 20 sites, all with 1 rep, can take part in any SE chat except SO/MSO), but not showing the icons and not included in the badges count, as far as I know. Only handful of users got many accounts to make a real change, so nobody really noticed this rep change before.

Comment: I've had the tons of accounts for a while; it comes with being a Charcoal member. The problem is that only now has it started showing *all* the accounts. The flair has only been showing the sites with 200+ rep before, I know.

Comment: @Mithrandir Ah, OK. Now it's clear. Definitely something changed. I have a feeling that we'll find out if it was intentional or not soon. And yes, I'm in the same club, shooting for Marshal badges with 101 rep, heh.

Comment: @JasonC I think it is not a big problem for a hotfix, but they will handle this as a top problem on their next workday. It will start at around 18:00 CET, tomorrow, and the flair generation script will run 5 hours later, at midnight GMT.